# Oracle Multi Select

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 CID    F_ID    NME
 1      A      QR
 1      B      QB
 2      A      QR
 3      B      QB
 4      A      QR
 4      B      QB
```

Result should be following way

```
CID    F_ID    NME
1       A     QR
1       B     QB
4       A     QR
4       B     QB
```

CID is the CUST ID, F_ID is the FUTURE_ID, NME IS NAME.

The query result should only return the CID that fall in both 
F_ID - A & B

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Yes Tried it with LISTAGG function but it's not fetching met the correct solution, is there a simple way for this multiselect

Answer (score 0):

Here is one canonical way of writing this query:

```
SELECT t1.CID, t1.F_ID, t1.NME
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CID
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE F_ID IN ('A', 'B')
    GROUP BY C_ID
    HAVING MIN(F_ID) <> MAX(F_ID)
) t2
    ON t1.CID = t2.CID;
```